# APC SMX3000 Smart-UPS Battery has never been cycled. Is it still good?

Tags: battery, apc, apc-smart-ups

I've recently inherited an APC SMX3000 Smart-UPS. The UPS has never been used.  Is the battery still good?

The battery is plugged in, but the UPS reports "No Batteries".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the battery is connected.

Really... you have to plug the internal battery in on new units, as they ship disconnected.

Has this been done? If not, definitely do it.

If you've done the basic things to troubleshoot, you can *always* call APC for support. *(they don't care how you acquired the UPS)*

[image]

Comment: "The battery is plugged in" was noted in the question.  Yes.  Of course the battery is plugged in.  Calling APC is good advice, however I wanted to see what others here thought because I imagined them urging me to replace the battery.

Comment: `I imagined them urging me to replace the battery` - Yes, logic would dictate that if the battery is plugged in but the UPS reports no battery then APC would recommend replacing the battery. I'd call them to confirm.